# Using the Range input parameter in QGIS Processing Model

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

I have built a model which requires a range of integers between `0 - 13` as an input. I am using two different `Number` parameter inputs, `Minimum` and `Maximum`, which works, but is somewhat awkward because the `Number` input is not an integer.

I have seen that there is a `Range` input available, which looks like a better fit, but I do not seem to be able to access the values of the input from algorithms.

Examples below, showing behaviour of Number vs Range parameter inputs

[image: Input GUI of Number parameters vs Range parameter]
*Input GUI of Number parameters vs Range parameter*

[image: Model builder - can't choose a Range value as input]
*Model builder - can't choose a Range value as input, only the Minimum and Maximum Number inputs*

Comment: As you've discovered, it appears that the `extract by attribute` algorithm doesn't accept a range as input. You'll have to run `extract by attribute` twice, once with the minimum and once with the maximum.

Comment: Yes, that is what I currently do (running once against the Minimum, then again against the Maximum Number inputs). What I am wondering is if there is anyway to access the min and max from Range input, as I prefer the UI for the Range input. In fact I haven't found any algorithms at all which accept a Range input.

Comment: I did a bit of testing in the modeler. The `extract by attribute` algorithm is a dead end; it's definitely not setup to accept a range as input. The `extract by expression` algorithm seems more promising. I'm thinking of an expression that uses the `parameter('myrange')` function (where `'myrange'` is the name of the range input) to call the range input. Where I'm stuck is finding a way to test if the field value of the current geometry object is within that range.  The `IN` operator requires a list of values, rather than a range.

Comment: FYI, the `r.rescale` algorithm accepts a range as input. So there's at least one algorithm that does.